# Which IPA sounds are similar?

Tags: phonetics, ipa

**Question**: Is there a matrix or table showing how audibly similar the different sounds from the IPA are? I'm looking for a scalar value that somehow measures the oral distance between two phonemes.

**Example:**
The following sounds are "close"

`ɑ` (f**a**ther) `ɛ` (dr**e**ss)

while the following sounds are "distant"

`b` (**b**uy) `n` (ca**n**)

**Nomenclature:** I'm putting quotes around "close" and "distant" since I don't know the proper term to quantify the oral similarity between two phonemes. Please edit or correct any mistakes I've made.

**Motivation**: I'm actually looking for this similarity matrix with a reduced set of the IPA, namely those sounds coming from the [ARPABET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arpabet).

Comment: You probably want a metric based on a featural characterisation of the sounds.

Comment: "Similar" is absolutely subjective, in fact any two objects in the Universe have somethings in common and are similar in something, e.g. `b` and `n` are also 'close' because both are voiced and both are consonants. You need to define what you mean by 'similar'.

Comment: @YellowSky I wish I could, but as I noted in my answer I lack the terminology. In a very ambiguous way, "similar" would be the average ranking provided by thousands of listeners. There will be a lot of variance, but there should be some features that are universal (I think?).   Perhaps something mentioned by Colin, the "featural characterisation" would suffice.

Comment: For consonants, the similarity is the hamming distance (# of bits different) of the feature matrix. For vowels, it's the distance in the [vowel trapezium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_diagram) (plus some features like rounding).

Comment: @Mitch, your comment looks like a good start for an answer to this question. I recommend expanding it into a full-sized answer, covering both vowels and consonants. There are other phonetic features as well, like tones, but they seem to be out of scope of the question.

Comment: Isn't there a difference between articulatory and auditory similarity? Features will explain the first, but not necessarily the second.

Comment: There are no speakers of IPA so the question is meaningless. One could ask specifically about confusability in English; or Spanish. There are multiple IPA transcriptions of English, so this will not tell you much about IPA.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As described (empirical similarity from many listeners), I think you want confusability, e.g. a ‘confusion matrix'. Here’s an example, from *Munson et al. (2003)*: https://doi.org/10.1121/1.1536630

Full reference:
Munson, B., Donaldson, G. S., Allen, S. L., Collison, E. A., & Nelson, D. A. (2003). Patterns of phoneme perception errors by listeners with cochlear implants as a function of overall speech perception ability. The Journal of the Acoustical Society of America, 113(2), 925-935.

Comment: this link be broken as of June 30, 2017

Comment: Here is an archived url: https://web.archive.org/web/20151003175728/http://www.tc.umn.edu/~munso005/ConfusionMatrices.pdf